# encrypt RSA by long text parts

Tags: rsa

Good afternoon,
Does anyone have any solution to encrypt large text in blocks using RSA algorithm
In the example below it works for small texts, the more I try the more large texts generates an error.

```
Dim RSA = New RSACryptoServiceProvider(1024)

        Dim dataToEncrypt() As Byte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("2010-05-18;2010-05-18T15:25;FAC 001/19;75.00;")

        Dim privKey = RSA.ExportParameters(True)
        Dim pubKey = RSA.ExportParameters(False)
        RSA.ImportParameters(pubKey)
        Dim encryptedData As Byte() = RSA.Encrypt(dataToEncrypt, False)
        RSA.ImportParameters(privKey)
        Dim EncryptedResult As String = System.Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedData)
        Dim EncrypetdResult As String = System.Text.Encoding.[Default].GetString(encryptedData)
        Dim decryptedData As Byte() = RSA.Decrypt(encryptedData, False)
        Dim texto = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptedData)
```

best regards
omateus

Comment: is there any routine that allows RSA encryption large data by blocks?

Comment: Why do you need to encrypt long text with RSA. We prefer hybrid encryption,

Comment: I need to certify software sales, and one of the requirements is rsa encryption

Comment: Are you trying to sign with RSA?

Comment: Good afternoon, yes

Comment: Signing RSA or not requires hash than sign paradigm. Look for RSA PSS.